getting an error when trying to duplicate table with DML
I was trying to duplicate data from an existing table to an empty table in different schema (all in the same database) and got an error. (PostgreSQL 16):
This is for specific exercise, so I have to copy using DDL & DML commands.  I have a better way, but I need this to work.
This is the error:

ERROR:  Key (name)=(Baker) already exists.duplicate key value violates unique constraint "job_pkey"


ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "job_pkey"


SQL state: 23505


Detail: Key (name)=(Baker) already exists.

The query I was tried to write look like this:
INSERT INTO table_copy.job_sample (name, description, salary)
SELECT      name, description, salary
FROM        table.job;


either the destination table is not empty (it already contains an entry for "Baker"), the two tables don't have the same constraints (duplicate names in the source table are ok) or you are inserting in the same table that you are reading.

Use an ON CONFLICT handler to deal with duplicates or clean the data before it even hits the database.
